# Eclipse always shows "add a breakpoint" icon in vertical ruler for every warning

Tags: eclipse

Recently (it seems), my Eclipse Mars (for Java) began showing an **add breakpoint** icon when I hover over warning icons in the vertical ruler. This requires me to move my mouse twice to actually see the warning, which is annoying because I don't need the **add a breakpoint** icon there.

Is there a way to hide the **add a breakpoint** icon with every warning? I don't know where to look in the preferences window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can either switch to a new IDE (like the new Eclipse Neon IDE) or use the "skip all breakpoints" button: 
[image: skip_all_breakpoint.png].

Comment: That doesn't affect the annotation to add a breakpoint from showing up during editing. The little dot is still there.

Comment: Oh... I've never had that warning , so I don't really know then.